# Use non-default keyring with gnome-keyring

Tags: debian, gpg, gnome-keyring

I'm using Gnome Keyring with GPG. Whenever I need to sign something, the keyring daemon takes over and does it for me.

However, if I do: `export GNUPGHOME=/path/to/keyring` from a Bash script and use `gpg` in that script, the keyring daemon doesn't take over.

Why is this? How can I change this, so that the keyring is used for other `$GNUPGHOME`s as well?

If I run `seahorse`, I can see that the password for the keys that exists in `/path/to/keyring` is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!

The problem was that the option `use-agent` wasnt enabled.

I had previously uncommented `use-agent` in `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` to be able to use the keyagent for my default keyring.

BUT, since I changed the homedir of the keyring, gpg was looking for a config in `/path/to/keyring/gpg.conf` instead and found nothing, since I only moved `pubring.gpg` and `secring.gpg` when I exported the keyring.